# Return row_number() of affected rows after an UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my C# application I'm executing multiple update queries to manipulate data in the database table. E.g. replace a specific character set into a different character set, insert new characters and remove characters. When a query like this has executed I want to do two things. Get the total rowcount of the affected rows and get a row_number() result set of the affected rows. The first thing is quite simple and is working already. The second thing however is something I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Here is an example of a query that I might use when I'm manipulating data:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = STUFF(myColumn, fromCharPos, toCharPos, 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(myColumn, fromCharPos, toCharPos), charToReplace, charReplacement)) 
WHERE LEN(myColumn) >= fromCharPos;
```

This query replaces (on all the cells of a column) a character set with another character set within a specified character range.

When this query has executed I want to get a result set of row numbers from the affected rows. Anyone know how I'm able to implement this?

Some things to consider:

- It has to work on atleast SERVER version 2005 and up.
- The UPDATE statements are executed within a transaction

**If anything is unclear, please comment below so I'm able to improve my question.**

Edit:
I noticed that it is not quite clear what I want to achieve.
Lets say we have a set of data that looks like this:

```
34.56.44.12.33
32.44.68
45.22.66.33.77
44.42.44
66.44.22.44.45
00.22.78
43.98.34.65.33
```

Now I want to replace the dots with an underscore between character position 9 to 12. That means that only these rows will be affected by the query:

```
 34.56.44.12.33 <--
 32.44.68
 45.22.66.33.77 <--
 44.42.44
 66.44.22.44.45 <--
 00.22.78
 43.98.34.65.33 <--
```

The thing I want to achieve is to get a row number result set of the affected rows. In my example that will be a result set like this:

```
Row_number()
1
3
5
7
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - He mentioned "The first thing is quite simple and is working already"

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get a result set of row numbers from the affected rows" can u explain a bit more on that.

Comment: Tables are inherently unordered. Rows don't have a built in "row number" so if you're wanting some row numbering, you have to tell us how to define an unambiguous ordering based on (some subset of) the actual columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```
declare @table table(val varchar(500))

insert into @table values
('34.56.44.12.33'),
('32.44.68'),
('45.22.66.33.77'),
('44.42.44'),
('66.44.22.44.45'),
('00.22.78'),
('43.98.34.65.33')


--select * from @table

declare @temp table(rowid int,val varchar(500), createdate datetime)
insert into @temp 
select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by val), val, GETDATE() from @table 

declare @rowEffectedCount int = 0
--select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by val), val, GETDATE() from @table WHERE CHARINDEX( '.',val,9 ) > 0

UPDATE @table 
SET val = 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX( '.',val,9 ), LEN(val)), ',', '_' ) 
WHERE CHARINDEX( '.',val,9 ) > 0
set @rowEffectedCount = @@ROWCOUNT

select @rowEffectedCount roweffected ,* from @temp t1
where val not in (
select val from @table )
```

**Old one** 
Its quite simple as my understanding.

You just add a one select query of your update query. read the comment for more understand

```
declare @rowEffectedCount int = 0

--you can use a temp table or permanet history table to take each work of portion.
--one thing to be carefull as structure is same or only save the pk , then no issue

--create table tempRowcount and insert the statement with the same where query, which filter the same data.
declare @t table(id int, createdate datetime)

select * into @t from myTable WHERE LEN(myColumn) >= fromCharPos
--or only pk
select id into @t from myTable WHERE LEN(myColumn) >= fromCharPos

--now update the 
UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = STUFF(myColumn, fromCharPos, toCharPos, 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(myColumn, fromCharPos, toCharPos), charToReplace, charReplacement)) 
WHERE LEN(myColumn) >= fromCharPos;


select * from @t
--finally delete or truncate or drop the table(if you use permanent table)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
CREATE TABLE #updatetablename
  (excolumn VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #updatetablename
VALUES      ('34.56.44.12.33'),
            ('32.44.68'),
            ('45.22.66.33.77'),
            ('44.42.44'),
            ('66.44.22.44.45'),
            ('00.22.78'),
            ('43.98.34.65.33')

DECLARE @temp TABLE
  (excolumn VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE
  (row_num  INT,excolumn VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @temp1
SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY excolumn),*
FROM   #updatetablename

UPDATE #updatetablename
SET    excolumn = Replace(excolumn, '.', '_')
output deleted.excolumn
INTO @temp
WHERE  Len(excolumn) > 12

SELECT b.row_num AS updatedrows,
       a.excolumn
FROM   @temp a
       JOIN @temp1 b
         ON a.excolumn = b.excolumn
```